# Do I need to start the game from the beginning to be able to use Kasumi DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-2

Do I need to start the game from the beginning to be able to use Kasumi DLC?

I started playing ME2 and I am just starting the second act – just finished the Horizon part. Then I bought Kasumi DLC.

Will I be able to use Kasumi in this game, or do I need to start again?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Kasumi DLC starts from the Citadel, so as long as you can get to the Citadel you are able to start the DLC. No need to start over from the beginning to play it.